# How to show available quantities by relating these two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, `tbl_storage_Depositor_Master` and `tbl_storage_Depositor_log`, one has total quantity like 1000 and the other has transaction of issues like 500,300,100.

Now I want to show data like this:

```
Date           issue quantity      available quantity
-----------------------------------------------------
20/10/2014          500                  500
21/10/2014          300                  200
21/10/2014          100                  100
```

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    mg.Godown_Name, [Bags_Weight],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ssd.[CreatedDate], 103) AS Date
FROM
    [tbl_storage_Depositor_log] AS sdl
INNER JOIN
    tbl_MetaData_GODOWN AS mg ON sdl.Godown_ID = mg.Godown_ID
INNER JOIN
    tbl_MetaData_STACK AS ms ON sdl.Stack_ID = ms.Stack_ID
WHERE 
    Depositor_Id = '232700'
```

which returns issue quantity, bags, godown and date like

```
date            godown            qty      availableqty
-------------------------------------------------------
20/10/2014         k1             500           ?
21/10/2014         k2             300           ?
```

How can I to calculate available quantity?

Please help.

as per answer but got errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by using `Recursive CTE`

**Schema setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     Dates          DATE,
     issue_quantity INT
  )

INSERT #test
VALUES ('10/20/2014',500 ),
       ('10/21/2014',300 ),
       ('10/21/2014',100 )
```

**Query**

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY dates) rn
         FROM   #test a),
     cte1
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 rn,
                      dates,
                      issue_quantity,
                      issue_quantity AS available_quantity
         FROM   cte
         ORDER  BY rn
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.rn,
                a.dates,
                a.issue_quantity,
                b.available_quantity - a.issue_quantity as available_quantity
         FROM   cte a
                INNER JOIN cte1 b
                        ON a.rn - 1 = b.rn)
SELECT dates,
       issue_quantity,
       available_quantity
FROM   cte1
```

**Result**

```
dates       issue_quantity  available_quantity
----------  --------------  ------------------
2014-10-20  500             500
2014-10-21  300             200
2014-10-21  100             100
```

**Update** try changing your query like this.

```
WITH cte(Godown_Name, Stack_Name, No_Of_Bags, Bags_Weight, CreatedDate, rn)
     AS (SELECT mg.Godown_Name,
                ms.Stack_Name,
                [No_Of_Bags],
                [Bags_Weight],
                ssd.CreatedDate,
                Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY ssd.[CreatedDate]) rn
         FROM   [tbl_Delivery_Stacking_Details_GatePass] AS ssd
                INNER JOIN tbl_MetaData_GODOWN AS mg
                        ON ssd.Godown_ID = mg.Godown_ID
                INNER JOIN tbl_MetaData_STACK AS ms
                        ON ssd.Stack_ID = ms.Stack_ID
         WHERE  Depositor_WR_Id = '232700'),
     cte1
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 Godown_Name,
                      Stack_Name,
                      No_Of_Bags,
                      Bags_Weight,
                      rn,
                      CreatedDate,
                      [Bags_Weight] AS available_quantity
         FROM   cte
         ORDER  BY rn
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.Godown_Name,
                a.Stack_Name,
                a.No_Of_Bags,
                a.[Bags_Weight],
                a.rn,
                a.CreatedDate,
                b.available_quantity - a.[Bags_Weight] AS available_quantity
         FROM   cte a
                INNER JOIN cte1 b
                        ON a.rn - 1 = b.rn)
SELECT CreatedDate,
       available_quantity
FROM   cte1
```

Comment: hi i am using following code but got error...Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "No_Of_Bags" of recursive query "cte1".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "rn" of recursive query "cte1".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "CreatedDate" of recursive query "cte1".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "available_quantity" o

Comment: @user3373573 - updated check now. you completely messed up the cte

Comment: thank now only one more error   Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "available_quantity" of recursive query "cte1".